# Wrong status value from bash script

Tags: bash, http, curl

My bash script runs `curl` command internally. I want to return the HTTP response code as the status of my script.

I'm doing this like here:

```
statusCode=404
if [ $statusCode -ne 200 ]
then
    echo $statusCode
    exit $statusCode
fi
exit 0
```

Status code is echoed properly (`404`), but status value (`$?`) is `148`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not possible to exit with HTTP response code from bash script,
because bash script can only exit with values `0-255`.
Value `404` overflowed and turned into `148`:

```
404 mod 256=148
```